# Onesignal sending a push notification with tag filter fails with "All included players are not subscribed"

Tags: php, curl, tags, push, onesignal

When i send a request to onesignal with the following curl:

```
curl -X POST \
  https://onesignal.com/api/v1/notifications \
  -H 'Authorization: Basic <omitted>' \
  -H 'Cache-Control: no-cache' \
  -H 'Content-Type: application/json' \
  -d '{
  "app_id": "<omitted>",
  "filters": [
    {"field": "tag", "key": "broodjes", "relation": "exists"}
  ],
  "contents": {"en": "English Message"}
}'
```

I'm trying to send a notification to all subscribed users with the tag "Broodjes".
Anywhere it says `omitted` I have omitted the value for obvious reasons.

Here is the unexpected response I get:

```
{
    "id": "",
    "recipients": 0,
    "errors": [
        "All included players are not subscribed"
    ]
}
```

And [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PeeyG.png) is an image of the users I'm trying to notify.

Answer (score 0):

It turned out that there was a trailing space on the end of my tag.